# Using AsyncTask, android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get an image from a server and use that file as the background fro my app.
Ive already leared that I should use AsyncTask to do so but my app still crashes or freezes when I run it.

Heres the code I use:

To call the AsyncTask:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent BG = new Intent((Intent) DownloadBGTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

The AsyncTask:

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.pxr.tutorial.json.Getbackground;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class DownloadBGTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Getbackground.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Things to be done while execution of long running operation
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // xecution of result of Long time consuming operation
    }
}
```

And the Getbackground.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.Environment;

public class Getbackground {
    URL url;

    public static long downloadFile(URL url2) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL ("http://oranjelan.nl/oranjelan-bg.png");
        InputStream input = url.openStream();{
        try {

            File fileOnSD=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
            String storagePath = fileOnSD.getAbsolutePath();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath + "/oranjelangbg.png");
                try {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    } finally {
            output.close();
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
   }    
 }    
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
         throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

PS, Sorry for the crappy code, I'm really new to this so dont be supprised if there are some really stupid misakes in there.

Comment: Can you tell where the app freezes or crashes? And you should really reformat your code, especially that { at `InputStream input = url.openStream();{
` is confusing..

Comment: Im already hanging on: Intent BG = new Intent((Intent) DownloadBGTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your comment says it's hanging on this line:

```java
Intent BG = new Intent((Intent) DownloadBGTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

let's start with that.

Since it sounds like you might be a newbie (no shame in that!), I'm guessing that you don't necessarily need this task to execute in parallel.

If you [read the Android docs on AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29), they kind of try to steer you away from that:

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

So, if you just want to pass a url, or a list of urls to the task to execute in order (series), then just start your task like this:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DownloadBGTask downloader = new DownloadBGTask();
    downloader.execute(new URL("http://www.google.com"), 
                       new URL("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

Where the strings are the URLs you want to retrieve (can be 1, or many).  The parameters to `execute()` get passed to your task's `doInBackground()` method.

---

**Edit:** Now that you seem to have gotten past **starting the task**, here's a couple other suggestions:

1. 1000000 bytes seems like a large buffer to me.  I'm not saying it won't work, but I usually use something like `byte[1024]`.
2. Concerning the directory where you store your downloads.  This is the code I like to use:

```java
private File mDownloadRootDir;
private Context mParent;        // usually this is set to the Activity using this code

private void callMeBeforeDownloading() {
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal
    mDownloadRootDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "/Android/data/" + mParent.getPackageName() + "/files/");
    if (!mDownloadRootDir.isDirectory()) {
        // this must be the first time we've attempted to download files, so create the proper external directories
        mDownloadRootDir.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

and later

```java
storagePath = mDownloadRootDir.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, indeed im a newbie to this. Im now using your code but I get an compiller error on: downloader.execute("http://oranjelan.nl/oranjelan-bg.png"); saying The method execute(URL...) in the type AsyncTask<URL,Integer,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @MichielT, no worries.  We were all newbies once!  By the way, I just updated my response, as I originally didn't realize that your task was taking `URL` objects instead of `String`s.

Comment: Nice, it is now getting past the call but now crashes on another piece of code, trying to find out where using breakpoints.

Comment: @MichielT, I added some more code above that *might* help, depending on what your next problem is ... I'm signing off for tonight :)

Comment: Nice, its working now! the file now downloads perfectly!! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use this utiity method to download an image from the web in your GetBackground class:

```
// Utiliy method to download image from the internet
    static private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,
                    bytes.length);
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Download failed, HTTP response code "
                    + statusCode + " - " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }
```

andyour  `DownloadBGTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap>`

```
URL url = new URL ("http://oranjelan.nl/oranjelan-bg.png");
DownloadBGTask task = new DownloadBGTask(); 
task.execute(url);
```

Comment: @MichielT You have not opened a connection to your url

Comment: not really, It does not get past the first call of the intent.

Comment: @MichielT why you are calling your aasynchronous task like this just use:
  DownloadBGTask task = new DownloadBGTask();
  task.execute(url);

Comment: @MichielT see updated answer and let me know if you still face problems